# Executing a C# program in a web form window

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I wrote a C# program that works good.

I want to execute that project, in a website, so the main form of my project will be in the web form.

I tried this code in the web application webform:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Program.Form1 y = new Program.Form1();
    y.ShowDialog();
}
```

and it works, but my program does not appear in the website, but in another window, and the website stays empty and in continuous linking trial condition.

How can I insert my program into the website window?

Comment: Wait, you want the *website* to host a winforms app?

Answer (score 4):

What you are calling a "C# Project" is a Windows Forms project. It it not compatible with ASP.NET. You cannot run it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Read about ASP.net, its a tool to develop websites with C#. Programs and websites are 2 different things and you can't run your program in a website. For example, you can't run games in your browser because it is written differently.
Read about it, its very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your projects is using the same language (in your case, C#, but it could also be VB) but WinForm applications and Web applications are two different things.  The make a long story short, the user interface of the first one will be Windows application installed on a machine while the second one will be displayed in a browser (and hosted on a web server).  The bottom line is that those project type cannot be mixed.

However, if you want to reuse some of your code in a Web or a WinForm application, you should consider creating a library project.  You'll be able to manage all the code that doesn't refer to specific UI from there and you'll be able to reference it from both of your projects.